# How to search files from one folder to next till found based upon a list file in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am looking for a batch file to do below tasks:

1) have a list file, say, list.txt 
   in this file:

```
12345.S3S
12346.S3S
12347.S3S
12348.S3S
12349.S3S
```

2) Now I want to have batch file to do the search from one folder to another till found. otherwise say not searched

```
folder1/ maybe only have 4 files
folder2  maybe only have 4 files
folder3  have all 5 files
```

So only folder3 shall be searched and output a file to list all these 5 files with path...

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

- It is expected to show your own coding efforts first.
- The following batch uses a fixed set of folders/files for
  demonstration - could as well be gathered dynamically.
- Provided neither folder names nor file names contain spaces:

---

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

Set "Folders=folder1 folder2 folder3"
Set "Files=12345.S3S 12346.S3S 12347.S3S 12348.S3S 12349.S3S"

CD /D "X:\Base\path"

For %%A in (%Folders%) Do (
    Set Cnt=0
    For %%B in (%Files%) Do (
        If Exist "%%A\%%B" Set /A Cnt+=1
    )
    If !Cnt!==5 (Set "Found=%%A"&Goto :Success)
)
Echo Fail couldn't find a folder with all file
Pause
Goto :Eof

:Success
Echo Found all of (%Files%) in %Found%
Pause
Goto :Eof
```

Sample run:

```
> tree . /F
A:\
├───folder1
│       12345.S3S
│       12347.S3S
│       12348.S3S
│       12349.S3S
├───folder2
│       12345.S3S
│       12346.S3S
│       12347.S3S
│       12349.S3S
└───folder3
        12345.S3S
        12346.S3S
        12347.S3S
        12348.S3S
        12349.S3S


> Q:\Test\2017\08\22\SO_45825229.cmd
Found all of (12345.S3S 12346.S3S 12347.S3S 12348.S3S 12349.S3S) in folder3
```

Comment: Hi LotPings, Is it possible to combine your code with this: FOR /F %%F IN (C:\auto_pkg_build\Sources\Source_schemes\%profile%\list.txt) DO DIR /s/p/b %%F.* >> C:\auto_pkg_build\Sources\Source_schemes\%profile%\finds.txt

Comment: Looks like you didn't grasp the concept of the batch. You need to test every file and count for every folder to check - this are two stacked for loops. If there are more files than five it is more efficient to abort the foldercheck if only one file is missing. Can all be done, but this is a new question.

Comment: If you find an answer helpful you should consider to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and/or [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)